# How to create this multi-column and multi-row table?

Tags: tables

How to create this table in latex.

```
Name    A   B   C         D    Name A   B    C      D


A   0   997 4.167   0.613   B   0   783 1.636   0.150
    0.04    1164    4.139   0.676       0.04    959 1.710   0.168
    0.08    1332    4.111   0.744       0.08    1135    1.783   0.187
    0.12    1499    4.083   0.817       0.12    1311    1.857   0.208
    0.16    1666    4.055   0.895       0.16    1487    1.930   0.231
    0.2 1834    4.028   0.980       0.2 1662    2.003   0.256
C   0   997 4.167   0.613   D   0   783 1.636   0.150
    0.04    1153    4.138   0.660       0.04    948 1.708   0.167
    0.08    1310    4.108   0.710       0.08    1113    1.780   0.184
    0.12    1466    4.079   0.763       0.12    1278    1.852   0.204
    0.16    1623    4.050   0.818       0.16    1443    1.924   0.224
    0.2 1779    4.020   0.877       0.2 1608    1.996   0.247
E   0   997 4.167   0.613   F   0   783 1.636   0.150
    0.04    1210    4.136   0.688       0.04    1004    1.706   0.169
    0.08    1423    4.104   0.769       0.08    1226    1.776   0.189
    0.12    1636    4.073   0.857       0.12    1447    1.846   0.211
    0.16    1849    4.042   0.953       0.16    1669    1.916   0.235
    0.2 2062    4.011   1.059       0.2 1890    1.986   0.262
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using the `booktabs` package for its well-styled horizontal rules and the `siunitx` package for its ability to align columns of numbers on their decimal points. I'd also insert a bit of vertical whitespace between the A/B, C/D, and E/F groups of numbers. Finally, I'd advise against using any vertical rules in the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}      
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=1.3} % default numerical column spec
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{l S[table-format=1.2] S[table-format=4.0] SS} @{}}
\toprule   % center non-numerical info (A, B, ...) by placing them in braces
Name & {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} & Name & {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-5}  \cmidrule(l){6-10} % leave gap between the two rules
A & 0    &  997 & 4.167 & 0.613 & B    & 0    &  783 & 1.636 & 0.150\\
  & 0.04 & 1164 & 4.139 & 0.676 &      & 0.04 &  959 & 1.710 & 0.168\\
  & 0.08 & 1332 & 4.111 & 0.744 &      & 0.08 & 1135 & 1.783 & 0.187\\
  & 0.12 & 1499 & 4.083 & 0.817 &      & 0.12 & 1311 & 1.857 & 0.208\\
  & 0.16 & 1666 & 4.055 & 0.895 &      & 0.16 & 1487 & 1.930 & 0.231\\
  & 0.2  & 1834 & 4.028 & 0.980 &      & 0.2  & 1662 & 2.003 & 0.256\\[1ex]
C & 0    &  997 & 4.167 & 0.613 & D    & 0    &  783 & 1.636 & 0.150\\
  & 0.04 & 1153 & 4.138 & 0.660 &      & 0.04 &  948 & 1.708 & 0.167\\
  & 0.08 & 1310 & 4.108 & 0.710 &      & 0.08 & 1113 & 1.780 & 0.184\\
  & 0.12 & 1466 & 4.079 & 0.763 &      & 0.12 & 1278 & 1.852 & 0.204\\
  & 0.16 & 1623 & 4.050 & 0.818 &      & 0.16 & 1443 & 1.924 & 0.224\\
  & 0.2  & 1779 & 4.020 & 0.877 &      & 0.2  & 1608 & 1.996 & 0.247\\[1ex]
E & 0    &  997 & 4.167 & 0.613 & F    & 0    &  783 & 1.636 & 0.150\\
  & 0.04 & 1210 & 4.136 & 0.688 &      & 0.04 & 1004 & 1.706 & 0.169\\
  & 0.08 & 1423 & 4.104 & 0.769 &      & 0.08 & 1226 & 1.776 & 0.189\\
  & 0.12 & 1636 & 4.073 & 0.857 &      & 0.12 & 1447 & 1.846 & 0.211\\
  & 0.16 & 1849 & 4.042 & 0.953 &      & 0.16 & 1669 & 1.916 & 0.235\\
  & 0.2  & 2062 & 4.011 & 1.059 &      & 0.2  & 1890 & 1.986 & 0.262\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this question should be answered the way it is right now ... http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/should-we-answer-really-bad-questions

Comment: More than 2 1/2 years after I posted this answer, it gets a downvote. Anyone care to explain why? What about the answer is so bad to prompt the downvote?